# How do I deal with a JSON.parse error coming from a Test in react when trying to mock localStorage?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs, local-storage

This is the error I'm getting.

```
 FAIL  src/tests/Game.test.js
   Game Component
    × Renders game part of the component when lastPlayed is null (157 ms)                                  
                                                                                                           
  ● Game Component › Renders game part of the component when lastPlayed is null             
                                                                                                           
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0                                                  
        at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)                                                                        
                                                                                                           
      19 |   function getTimeDiff() {                                                                      
      20 |     let currentDay = new Date().toISOString();
    > 21 |     let prevPlay = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("lastplayed"));
         |                         ^
      22 |     let diff = differenceInHours(parseISO(currentDay), parseISO(prevPlay));
      23 |     console.log(currentDay + " and " + prevPlay);
      24 |

      at getTimeDiff (src/Game.js:21:25)
```

However, technically if the mock was working properly, and lastplayed was set to null, the function getTimeDiff() shouldn't even be called

This is the conditional within the Game component:

```
return(
<div>
{localStorage.getItem("lastplayed") === null || getTimeDiff() >= 24 ? (<SubComponent/>):(<AnotherComponent/>) }
</div>
)
```

this is my test file, I got the [mockStorage code from here](https://bholmes.dev/blog/mocking-browser-apis-fetch-localstorage-dates-the-easy-way-with-jest/#link-what-if-we-could-mock-browser-storage-directly)

```
let mockStorage = {};

beforeAll(() => {
  global.Storage.prototype.setItem = jest.fn((key, value) => {
    mockStorage[key] = value;
  });
  global.Storage.prototype.getItem = jest.fn((key) => mockStorage[key]);
});

beforeEach(() => {
  mockStorage = {};
});

afterAll(() => {
  global.Storage.prototype.setItem.mockReset();
  global.Storage.prototype.getItem.mockReset();
});

afterEach(cleanup);

describe("Game Component", () => {
  it("Renders game part of the component when lastPlayed is null", () => {
    localStorage.setItem("lastPlayed", null);
    render(<Game />);
    expect(screen.getByTestId("title-header")).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(screen.getByTestId("game-status-div")).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(screen.queryByText("That's it for today")).not.toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(global.Storage.prototype.setItem).toHaveBeenCalledOnce();
    expect(mockStorage["lastPlayed"]).toEqual(null);
  });
});
```

Comment: `Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0` - most likely the thing that is being "parsed" is `undefined` .... that's where the `u` comes from - though ... `localStorage.getItem` never returns `undefined` ... so that's a mystery - unless that item in localStorage is the string `"undefined"` I guess

Comment: @JaromandaX What about `global.Storage`? It appears (from a brief glance through the linked code) it can return `undefined` quite readily.

Comment: @HereticMonkey - hmm, but the code that throws specifically is using localStorage ... `localStorage.getItem("lastplayed")` - oh, right ... i see what you mean

Comment: @JaromandaX One wonders why `mockStorage` is there at all then... Oh, I see, `localStorage` calls `window.Storage.prototype.getItem`/`setItem`

Answer (score 0):

The implementation of `getItem` needs to be updated to work the same as the standard implementation. So instead of:

```
global.Storage.prototype.getItem = jest.fn((key) => mockStorage[key]);
```

It should be something along the lines of

```
global.Storage.prototype.getItem = jest.fn((key) => mockStorage[key] ?? null);
```

So that if a key is not present, `null` is returned rather than `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't seem to fix the issue for me. I can't seem to find a situation online where someone is trying to both set and retrieve the localStorage as a test, so maybe testing for this isn't worth it.